# HMR loop reboot with .Net Core 2.1.2 + Angular 6 when Https is enabled

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

To enable https on .Net Core 2.1.2, I added:

```
        //https
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseHsts();
```

Then I enabled SSL option in the properties of my projet in the tab "debug".

The api works correctly.

For Angular 6, in angular.json, I modified the npm run start command with:

```
 ng serve --ssl --ssl-key certificate.key --ssl-cert certificate.crt --proxy-config proxy.config.json
```

And I updated the proxy.config.json by adding the new https link to my api.

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "https://localhost:44313/",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

Note: it s important to let secure to false, because I didnt generate the ssl certificate in localhost. When you put the option to true, Angular wont accept unsafe ssl call.

When I load the angular App, the site load correctly then I see in the console [WDS] Disconnected and then the website reboot, sometimes one time, sometime many times.

How to make HMR works without loop reboot for .Net Core 2.1.2 with Angular 6 when Https is enabled?

Comment: I found this issue here:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5826

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because my Angular App was not considered as safe by my browser. So I followed these instructions:
https://medium.com/@rubenvermeulen/running-angular-cli-over-https-with-a-trusted-certificate-4a0d5f92747a

- generate certificate + key
- authorize certificate in "Trusted Root Certification Authorities"
- update package.json with:

  > "start": "ng serve --ssl true --ssl-cert ssl/server.crt --ssl-key ssl/server.key --proxy-config proxy.config.json"
- run :

  > npm run start
- launch https://locahost:4200

And now every things works correctly.